# looking for option to get the father text

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the text only from a father element. See below:

```
`<h2 class="maps-header-text-h1">
ABC 
<span id="currentMapCategory">DEF</span>
</h2>`
```

when i'm doing getText from `.maps-header-text-h1` i'm getting all the the text of the element that mean ABCDEF, what i want is to get only the ABC without using JS if it possible? and to understand why the two text together while i locate only the first element

These is the [URL](https://maps.b144.co.il/#)
the element is `.maps-header-text-h1` and under it you can see there is other text too

Thank you

Comment: This is an interesting case, I would always expect that locating the `h2` element would only return text from the `h2`, and not include any text from its `span` child.

Comment: @Christine me too, but it's look that they are connected somehow, i saw these on the debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're several solutions:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".maps-header-text-h1 #currentMapCategory"));
String headerText = (String) js.executeScript("return arguments[0].previousSibling.textContent", element).trim();
```

Second:

```
String headerText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".maps-header-text-h1")).getText();
String mapCategoryText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#currentMapCategory")).getText();

String headerText = headerText.replace(mapCategoryText, "").trim();
```

Third:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".maps-header-text-h1"));
String headerText = (String) js.executeScript("return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent", element).trim();
```

One more from @KunduK:

```
// split("\\s") means split by whitespace, that can be space, tab, newline.. 
String headerText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".maps-header-text-h1"))
    .getText().trim()
    .split("\\s")[0];
```

Comment: For second option if you split the `headerText` with space and print the index 0 . `String[] lines = headerText.split(" ");
        System.out.println(lines[0]);`

Comment: Thanks.
whats the explain of these line?
`String headerText = (String) js.executeScript("return arguments[0].previousSibling.textContent", element).trim();
` 
and what is the difference in terms of speed between them?

Comment: @KunduK yes also as an option.

Comment: @nuzo all very fast, you'll not feel the difference

Comment: @Sers trim is throwing the white spaces before and after the text, spit is doing that between  the text?
about the trim, there is new line after the first text?
also `arguments[0].previousSibling.textContent", element` means the located element (0) and than it goes to the request parameter , and then element, and what to do with him? these is the explain?

Comment: Yes correct. Trip remove white spaces before and after the text then split separates text with what to put as an argument and give you back array. I used split with \s regular expression that means any whitespace character include new line.

Comment: argument[0] means parameter for executeScript function. Value for the parameter is element after a comma. Code executes plain javascript

Comment: @Sers now i understand,
Thank you

Answer (score -2):

Try using `element.getAttribute("value")` for you weblement that you are finding using `css`.

Comment: did that with no success

Comment: can you share the url for the web?

Comment: and what exactly you are looking for? Which element on the screen should i inspect?

Comment: i'm looking for the [main header](https://imgur.com/iuKerGX) under the Tabs

Comment: its good that you got the answer, i couldn't understand the language.

Comment: it's something different than regular text, it's connected to other text that why as far as i understand the text there